# Retrieving image from parse.com

Tags: iphone, ios, image, parsing

I don't know if this is possible but I think it could be possible and I dont know how to do this. I simply want to load an image from parse.com like you retrieve objects from parse.com. Should I do it the same way I get strings from parse.com? I just found how to save images on parse but not how to get them. I would be happy if someone could show me a link to do this or a sample code.

I've already set up a string which is retrieved from parse:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"app"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"ID"
                             block:^(PFObject *textdu, NSError *error) {
                                 if (!error) {



                                     UIFont *welcomeLabelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];

                                     welcomeLabel.text = [textdu objectForKey:@"ueberschriftnews"];
                                     welcomeLabel.font = welcomeLabelFont;
                                     welcomeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                     welcomeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                                     welcomeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                                     welcomeLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                     welcomeLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
                                     [contentView addSubview:welcomeLabel];



                                     // The get request succeeded. Log the score
                                     NSString *text = [textdu objectForKey:@"newstext"];
                                     UIFont *font = nil;
                                     CGFloat points = 17;
                                     CGFloat maxHeight = infoLabel.frame.size.height;
                                     CGFloat textHeight;
                                     do {
                                         font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:points];
                                         CGSize size = CGSizeMake(infoLabelRect.size.width, 100000);
                                         CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
                                         textHeight = textSize.height;
                                         points -= 1;
                                     } while (textHeight > maxHeight);
                                     infoLabel.text = text;
                                     infoLabel.numberOfLines = 9;
                                     infoLabel.font = font;
                                     infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                     infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                                     infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                                     infoLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                     infoLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

                                     [infoLabel sizeToFit];
                                     [contentView addSubview:infoLabel];

                                 } else {

                                     infoLabel.text = @"something";
                                     [infoLabel sizeToFit];
                                     [contentView addSubview:infoLabel];
                                 }

                             }];
```

My parse set up:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. If you use web interface to instead of string you should specify PFFile as a type. If you upload image from your iOS client here is a link to parse iOS guide how to do that https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS .
Once your image is there you can download image this way:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"app"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"ID"
                         block:^(PFObject *textdu, NSError *error) {
{
     // do your thing with text 
     if (!error) {
          PFFile *imageFile = [textdu objectForKey:@"image"];
          [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
              if (!error) {
                  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
              }
          }];
     }
 }];
```

Comment: I'll test it..one moment pls :D

Comment: Well, all the rest should be the same with the case when you get strings :). You probably need a query to get parseObject (PFObject) which has a PFFile property.

Comment: The code I gave you implies that PFObject parseObject has a PFFile property named "image"

Comment: Look at my question below. I updated it. Could you help me with this and implement the retrieving of the image.

Comment: In germany you say "ich stehe in deiner Schuld" that means something like "I owe you something" ;)