# Retrieving Image from Parse.com into Processing sketch

Tags: parse-platform, processing

I want to retrieve images from a Parse.com database to a Processing sketch. Is that possible?
Where to start? Can't find any info about it.

Comment: Have you checked this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690655/retrieving-image-from-parse-com

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Its for IOS and I need to retrieve images into a Processing Sketch...  :-)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

From my brief viewing of the Processing language, it seems you can call `loadImage(url)`. All that is needed is to get the URL of the image, which will depend on which language you're using to access Parse.

For example in JavaScript:

```
var url = parseObject.get('imageProperty').url();
```