# Load image from parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How do I load images and image text saved in parse.com?

This is my function for uploading the image:

```
func uploadPost(){
        var imageText = self.imageText.text

        if (imageView.image == nil){
            println("No image uploaded")
        }
        else{
            var posts = PFObject(className: "Posts")
            posts["imageText"] = imageText
            posts["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    //**Success saving, now save image.**//

                    // Create an image data
                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)
                    // Create a parse file to store in cloud
                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "upload_image.png", data: imageData)
                    posts["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
                    posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            // Take user home
                            println("Data uploaded")
                        }
                        else{
                            println(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
                else{
                    println(error)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

How can i add image and text in tableview, and make it a scroll look-a-like like instagram if there are more then 1 image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving image from parse.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690655/retrieving-image-from-parse-com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to load an image from parse

```
PFFile *profile = user[@"profilePic"];
            if (profile)
            {
                [profile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        UIImage *profilePic = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        //Here is your image use it
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //error
                    }

                }];
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

First part of question is duplicate as remus pointed out:
[Retrieving image from parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690655/retrieving-image-from-parse-com) You will need to query for the image data and convert to a uiimage.

Second part of question:

Just store the queried images and text in array, then make custom uitableviewcells that hold a uiimageview and textview. Populate the tableviewcells with data from array.

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to an existing question; use the flag option to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, will note for future. I figured that since there was more to his question than just a duplicate I would link and answer the other part of his question.

Comment: @Rasputin - Could you show an example code from your question please?